# Textview background Size

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, textview

I have textview in my layout as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/notif"
    android:textColor="@color/wallet_bright_foreground_holo_dark"/>
```

Is there any way I can get the background size of the textview to fit the text that dynamically populate it with?

Comment: Take a Look at here 
http://vmustafayev4en.blogspot.in/2012/02/setting-background-image-of-android.html

Comment: It sounds like you want the background image to grow/shrink dynamically depending on the string length of the TextView's text that is set at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically get your background size, you can use:

```
tv = (TextView)...findViewById(...);
BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable)tv.getBackground();
```

Then to get height and length use:

```
background.getTileModeX();
background.getTileModeY()
```

Hope it will solve your problem.